# How to exclude validation for blank space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression in my code to validate a textbox. The expression validates a certain format of text. However, I want the case where the user leaves the textbox blank to also be valid. This regex doesn't match when I submit form with blank text box. I want to remove this case. How do I do that?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Comment: Please provide sample text on which you are running the regex.

Comment: You can find the explanation of a regex at many websites including [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just make your entire match conditional....

```
^([A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})){0,1}$
```

http://regexr.com/38ojr

Surrounding the entire expression (excluding the `^` and `$` start and end anchors) in `(...){0,1}` instructs the regex engine to match the bracketed expression 0 or 1 times. matching 0 times results in an empty string passing validation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression to check for 'blank text'. Just trim the value and check its length (so `value.trim().length < 1`)

Comment: I have to use only a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `+` to `*`.

The `+` after the first class in the regex means 1 or more results.

The `*` will mean it can be empty.

Your regex will now be: `^([A-Za-z0-9-]*(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})){0,1}$`

Comment: This will permit the string to start with `backslash` ? I don't believe that is what the OP requires?